# C or C++ Heap Memory Management Implementations

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

Can someone point me to a few open source heap implementations which are not part of a huge library like GLIB.

I need one with the following features:

- Single Threaded
- The whole heap can be freed with a single call.
- Small footprint because i need to use one heap for each list/tree widget in my GUI.

I think there should be a lot of existing stuff. I remember i had to implement a simple first-fit heap allocator myself in university courses twice.

For C++ it must not use the standard c++ libraries or templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at: http://www.25thandclement.com/~william/projects/libarena.html

You might also want to watch this presentation: http://www.slideshare.net/emery/composing-highperformance-memory-allocators-with-heap-layers